# jqGrid with ASP.NET MVC problem displaying records

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using Craig Stuntz article on Using jqGrid with ASP.NET MVC: Search and Formatting, http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/27/38243/
Using HttpFox I can see the json data being returned successfully but it will not display in the grid. The displays fine, but with no data and page numbers. Can anyone see a problem with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: '/Grid/DynamicGridData/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['EnquiryID', 'FirstName', 'Surname', 'PostCode'],
    colModel: [
      { name: 'EnquiryID', index: 'EnquiryID', width: 80, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'Surname', index: 'Surname', width: 150, align: 'left' },
      { name: 'PostCode', index: 'PostCode', width: 150, align: 'left'}],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    sortname: 'EnquiryID',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    imgpath: '/scripts/themes/steel/images',
    caption: 'My first grid'
});
$("#search").filterGrid("#grid", {
    gridModel: false,
    filterModel: [{
        label: 'Search',
        name: 'search',
        stype: 'text'
        }]

    });

});
```

Calling the above:

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content          ("~/Scripts/Home.GridDemo.js") %>"></script>

<div id="search"></div>  
<table id="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager"  style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

Comment: 1. Are you calling setGridDefaults elsewhere? If so, please show it. If not, you need to add the additional options from setGridDefaults in my example to the call to the jqGrid method. 2. If that doesn't solve the problem, please show your JSON.

Comment: The above was a variant on your example, I can see where the problem is now. Thanks

Comment: You should post your solution so others can solve similar problems.

Comment: (As an answer, that is; you're allowed to answer your own question.)

Answer (score 1):

The setGridDefaults need to be set as in the article:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
GridDemo.Home.GridDemo.setupGrid($("#grid"), $("#pager"), $("#search"));
});

GridDemo.Home.GridDemo = {
setupGrid: function(grid, pager, search) {
    grid.jqGrid({
    colNames: ['Int', 'String', 'Date'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'IntProperty', index: 'IntProperty' },
                    { name: 'StringProperty', index: 'StringProperty' },
                    { name: 'DateProperty', index: 'DateProperty' }, 
                  ],
        pager: pager,
        sortname: 'IntProperty',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50],
        sortorder: "asc",
        url: "GridDemoData"
    }).navGrid(pager, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });        
    search.filterGrid("#" + grid.attr("id"), {
        gridModel: false,
        filterModel: [{
            label: 'Search',
            name: 'search',
            stype: 'text'
        }]
    });
}
```

};

Comment: chances are you forgot to set repeatitems to false; it doesn't matter whether you do it as default or not.  I happened to be following the same trail and was getting the same behavior.

Comment: what is 'setGridDefaults'? I can't find it in your codes. Is it the setupGrid function? If so, why do you and Stuntz call it 'setGridDefaults'?

Answer (score -5):

I think it is easier just to build your own grid table. Here is an example that uses alternating row colors,

```
<table class="results" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
<thead class="tablehead">
  <tr> 
    <td width="55px"><b>Country</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>State</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>City</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>Town</b></td>
    <td width="55px"><b>Postal</b></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% 
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<MY_RESULTS>)ViewData["My_Results"])
    {
        if (count % 2 == 0) { Response.Write("<tr class='even'>"); } else { Response.Write("<tr class='odd'>"); }   
    %>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Country)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.State)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.City)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Town)%></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Postal)%></td>
        </tr>

    <% count += 1; } %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You just need to set up css class for odd, even, and tablehead background colors.

Comment: That does about 0.02% of what jqGrid does.

Comment: I never said it was a replacement, I just find it easy to work with and customize.. <><